# Tableau - lookup letter grade from range

Tags: excel, tableau-api, letter

I have two Excel spreadsheets. One contains average numerical grade for a student and the other a list of letter grades for numeric grades between a min and max

Spreadsheet 1

```
Student   Avg    Letter Grade
Mike       91
Joe        76
Mary       84
Sally      78

Spreadsheet 2
Min        Max        LetterGrade
90          100          A
81           89          B
71           80          C
61           70          D
0            60          F
```

How do I return the proper grade for each student in Tableau?  It seems trivial but I can't figure out the calculation.  Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: The function you want is `VLOOKUP`  Review that function; try it out, and post back with your efforts if you run into trouble, with examples of your formula, actual output, and desired output.

Comment: Best way to do that is using multiple IF and ELSEIF statements. No straightforward way to connect both sheets. You can try some elaborate SQL join, but not advised in this particular case (in which 5 ELSEIF statements suffice)

Comment: Since the numbers in the second spreadsheet are in descending order, the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-e2fba01b-188c-4057-87e2-df6bb4075817) will not be your best option unless you are prepared to reverse them into ascending order. An `INDEX(MATCH(...))` pair will do as the [MATCH function](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-bc9d55b1-2e79-4a70-adda-c1dbec6aa7e5) can be used on numbers in a descending order when the *match_type* parameter is `-1`.

Comment: This is a very common use of VLOOKUP. Here's one web page showing how: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2009/06/01/convert-percentages-to-letter-grades-with-vlookup/

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this by using Groups.

1. Import Spreadsheet 1 as a data source
2. Right Click on "Avg" and select Create Group
3. From there use Shift Click to group your ranges using Spreadsheet 2 as your reference, using labels "A, B, C"
4. On the top of the Create Group dialog box, make sure you rename your Field Name as "Letter Grade"

The weakness of this approach is that you have to check/redefine your groups if you are updating your data source. Using IF-ELSEIF statements may be more flexible as Inox suggested in the comments. But this is a relatively easy trick, without any programming involved. :-)

For more info, visit: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/use-ad-hoc-groups-categorize

Hope this helps!